# BIRT - Render displayText property for selected parameter values

Tags: java, parameters, birt

I have a report in which I am needing to display a parameter in the header.

The parameter is a dynamic list box allowing multiple selections.

Placing a dynamic text box in my report header with the following expression results in "null" being output when it is actually not null:

```
params["parameterName"].displayText
```

Using the following code produces numeric output (as expected)

```
params["parameterName"].value
```

How can I display the actual associated text(s) of the parameter selection(s) made at run-time?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve a similar problem with the `reportContext.getParameterDisplayText()` function, but found it difficult to work with it.

If you still want to solve your problem with this approach, you can look here as a start: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/159083/

### I developed the following workaround for my requirements:

1) First you need two datasets. one for the actual parameter, the second provides the data for displaying the selection:

*Parameter DataSet query:*

```
select 'A' AS name,
        1 AS id 

UNION ALL

select 'B' AS name,
        2 AS id 

UNION ALL

select 'C' AS name,
        3 AS id
```

*Display DataSet query:*

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT paramTbl.name ORDER BY paramTbl.id  SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'displayText' 
FROM
(select 'A' AS name,
        1 AS id 

UNION ALL

select 'B' AS name,
        2 AS id 

UNION ALL

select 'C' AS name,
        3 AS id
) AS paramTbl

WHERE paramTbl.id IN('xxx')
```

2) Then a script is used in the beforeOpen event of the second DataSet to replace the 'xxx' string in the where of the query with the values ​​of the parameter selection:

```
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("xxx", params["Parameter"].value.join("','" ));
```

[image: before open script]

3) Now you can add a data element to the report, add a binding for the second data set and output the one column that contains the display values ​​of the parameter concatenated by GROUP_CONCAT
[image: data binding]

The output of the parameter selection looks like this at the end:
[image: parameter selection]
[image: parameter displayText]